# float listview ontop of an activity

Tags: android, facebook, listview, android-listview

How to get floating listview on top of another activity like in android facebook app.I tried to do it but I dont know how to proceed .

I am trying to create listview with toggle imagebutton on top which displays listview with linear fade down animation over already existing view .Here is a   link to what I am talking about

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [handytechplus.com](http://handytechplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/facebook-apps-for-mobile-phones.jpg))</sub>

Rally appreciate any help or seek clarity in the above question.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use custom spinner like that [link](http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html)

Comment: it does not look good .I am looking at something same like popover uitableview  in ios implementation

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using a custom ListFragment, sitting on top of your data.
As RelativeLayout works, the lower the item is in your xml, the higher its Z-axis will be.
Create a new class extending ListFragment, put it in the XML.
when you want the layout closed, just set the visibility of the View (Fragment) to "gone" and vise-versa.
About the animation, check the Android developer site about changing visibility animation.

**EDIT:**
About creating Fragment and implementing in the XML : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
To change visibility : 
`((CustomFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment)).setVisibility(View.GONE);` 
Make sure you use FragmentActivity as your activity and support4.ListFragment instead of the regular ListFragment.

Comment: can you share sample code or link where I can find something similar.Thanks for that

Comment: Thanks will try to implement the above and get back to you quickly if I have any doubts